# Homestead with subdomains

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, homestead

I use homestead and Laravel 5.4 and I need to enable sub-domains, in my main windows 10 machine I added a hosts in (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) record :

```
192.168.10.10   myapp.dev
192.168.10.10   website.myapp.dev
```

so this works ok, when I navigate to website.myapp.dev it displays homepage as if I go to myapp.dev, and also my homestead server is apache2 not nginx

In this route when I go to website.myapp.dev I get the expected output (website.myapp.dev) in the log:

```
Route::get('/',   function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    \Log::info($request->fullUrl()); // logs website.bikser.dev

});
```

however my this route is not firing up when I go to website.myapp.dev :

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.dev')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/{account}',    'WebsiteController@view');
});
```

So I need this route to work so I could use sub-domains , I didn't change anything in .htaccess file coz I don't know if I should and also I tried to edit `apache2.conf` and add this lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName myapp.dev

ServerAlias *.myapp.dev

</VirtualHost>
```

but still my `{account}.myapp.dev` route does not fire up , pls help

EDIT:

just added this code as was suggested by : @headmax, but when I navigate to  myapp.dev it says

NotFoundHttpException , this is the code that I added :

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName myapp.dev 
DocumentRoot home/vagrant/code/public 
<Directory "home/vagrant/code/public/">  
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All 
  #Require local  
  Require all granted 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the right of your new doc root :

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER home/vagrant/code/public
```

> Note: The default Apache configuration in Debian 8 requires that each
>   virtual host file end in .conf.

We **copy** the **default vhost** for your own site.conf **000-default.conf**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.dev.conf
```

You need to edit the file and add here your ***virtualhost paste***

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.dev.conf
```

We need the simple way look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myapp.dev
    ServerName myapp.dev
    ServerAlias www.myapp.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/code/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now that we have created our virtual host files, we can enable.

```
sudo a2ensite myapp.dev.conf
```

> **Output**: Enabling site myapp.dev. To activate the new configuration,
>   you need to run:   service apache2 reload

Restart Apache

```
service apache2 reload //to reload configuration
sudo systemctl restart apache2 //to apply the configuration change
```

*Now your are done test the site.*

You need a **root directory** to tell apache where are stored you site files.
Here example **myapp.dev is a folder** and the **public folder** are (a child) where public files stored.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName myapp.dev 
DocumentRoot home/vagrant/code/public 
<Directory "home/vagrant/code/public/">  
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All 
  #Require local  
  Require all granted 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @Mikail Mika i edited and adapt to you context, i just add the and tag </VirtualHost> missed and the <Directory "home/vagrant/code/public/" slash at the end missed too. Regards.

Comment: thank you man, but it still does not work, when I got to `website.myapp.dev` or `myapp.dev` it throws `NotFoundHttpException ` however other routes such as `myapp.dev/something`  work  , do you use the above code in homestead ?

Comment: Do you put this virtual on the good file? if you are on linux you need to add  you new doc root with the good rights and settings before this step. addin the process on my first post.